# Procedural Generated Rooms (Like Binding of Isaac)

Tags: java, eclipse, procedural

I'm making a simple procedural generated dungeon where your character spawns in a room with randomly opened or closed doors in random direction. This is already complete.

When the character leaves the room it will generate new random numbers for a new room. Storing the numbers of the old room and to generate a room with those numbers if the character travels backwards. This part isn't finished, but would be easy to do, but I don't want to do that yet, because it will cause the problem below.

How could I create something that could store that no matter where the player travels and know when to use the variables? How could I automatically create variables like that?

Current Code:

```
public class Executable extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
Container contentPane=this.getContentPane();
Graphics bufferGraphics;

int xAxis; //Universal Variables:
int yAxis;
int characterX=463;
int characterY=486;
int oldCharacterX=463;
int oldCharacterY=486;
Image characterNorth = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterNorth.jpg").getImage();
Image characterEast = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterEast.jpg").getImage();
Image characterSouth = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterSouth.jpg").getImage();
Image characterWest = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterWest.jpg").getImage();
Image brickWall = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/brickWall.jpg").getImage();
Image brickFloor = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/brickFloor.jpg").getImage();
Image character=characterNorth;
boolean pressed=false;
static boolean northDoor;
static boolean eastDoor;
static boolean southDoor;
static boolean westDoor;
static boolean Randomizer=true;
static int north;
static int east;
static int south;
static int west;
static Random r=new Random();
boolean doorOpen=false;

public static void main(String[] args) { //Main
    north=r.nextInt(3)+1;
    east=r.nextInt(3)+1;
    south=r.nextInt(3)+1;
    west=r.nextInt(3)+1;
    if(north==1) {
        northDoor=true;
    }else {
        northDoor=false;
    }
    if(east==1) {
        eastDoor=true;
    }else {
        eastDoor=false;
    }
    if(south==1) {
        southDoor=true;
    }else {
        southDoor=false;
    }
    if(west==1) {
        westDoor=true;
    }else {
        westDoor=false;
    }
    Executable e=new Executable();
}

public Executable() { //Canvas
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 1680, 1050);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) { //Paint 

    for(xAxis=58;xAxis<=858;xAxis=xAxis+50) {
        for(yAxis=81;yAxis<=881;yAxis=yAxis+50) {
            g.drawImage(brickFloor,xAxis,yAxis,null);
        }
        yAxis=31;
    }
    for(xAxis=8;xAxis<958;xAxis=xAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }
    yAxis=931;
    for(xAxis=8;xAxis<=908;xAxis=xAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }
    xAxis=8;
    for(yAxis=81;yAxis<=881;yAxis=yAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }
    xAxis=908;
    for(yAxis=81;yAxis<=881;yAxis=yAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }

    while(!doorOpen) {
        if(northDoor==false && eastDoor==false && southDoor==false && westDoor==false) {
            north=r.nextInt(3)+1;
            east=r.nextInt(3)+1;
            south=r.nextInt(3)+1;
            west=r.nextInt(3)+1;
            if(north==1) {
                northDoor=true;
            }else {
                northDoor=false;
            }
            if(east==1) {
                eastDoor=true;
            }else {
                eastDoor=false;
            }
            if(south==1) {
                southDoor=true;
            }else {
                southDoor=false;
            }
            if(west==1) {
                westDoor=true;
            }else {
                westDoor=false;
            }
        }else {
            doorOpen=true;
        }
    }

    if(northDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,458,31,null);
    }
    if(eastDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,908,481,null);
    }
    if(southDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,458,931,null);
    }
    if(westDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,8,481,null);
    }

    g.drawImage(character,characterX,characterY,null);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) { //Character rotation and movement.
    if(pressed==false) {
        pressed=true;
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            if(character==characterNorth) {
                if(characterY>86 && characterX>13 && characterX<913) {
                    characterY=characterY-50;
                }else if(northDoor && characterX==463) {
                    oldCharacterY=characterY;
                    characterY=characterY-50;
                }
            }else {
                character=characterNorth;
            }
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            if(character==characterWest && characterY>36 && characterY<926) {
                if(characterX>63) {  //and y is greater than and less than
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX-50;
                }else if(westDoor && characterY==486) {
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX-50;
                }
            }else {
                character=characterWest;
            }
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            if(character==characterSouth) {
                if(characterY<871 && characterX>13 && characterX<913) {
                    oldCharacterY=characterY;
                    characterY=characterY+50;
                }else if(southDoor && characterX==463) {
                    oldCharacterY=characterY;
                    characterY=characterY+50;
                }
            }else {
                character=characterSouth;
            }
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            if(character==characterEast && characterY>36 && characterY<926) {
                if(characterX<848) {  //and y is greater than and less than
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX+50;
                }else if(eastDoor && characterY==486) {
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX+50;
                }
            }else {
                 character=characterEast;
            }
        }
        repaint(oldCharacterX,oldCharacterY,40,40);
        repaint(characterX,characterY,40,40);
        }
    }

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) { //Prevents keys from being held down.
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        pressed=false;
    }
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
        pressed=false;
    }
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        pressed=false;
    }
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        pressed=false;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to store the random number associated with each room and then traverse backward, in order, through the random numbers, a stack is the data structure you are looking for. To gain a conceptual understanding of a stack, see [Stack (abstract data type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). In short, a stack is like a pile of papers, where the last item placed at the top of the pile is the first element removed from the pile when traversing through the papers, termed Last-in-First-out (LIFO) ordering.

In Java, a `Deque` (double-ended queue, pronounced "deck") can be used as a stack. To put an element on the top of the stack, you use the `push` method and remove an element from the top of the stack, you use the `pop` method (note that `pop` both obtains the value at the top of the stack and removes it from the stack). For example:

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
stack.push(10);
stack.push(20);
System.out.println(stack.pop());
stack.push(30);
System.out.println(stack.pop());
System.out.println(stack.pop());
```

This code will produce the following output:

```
20
30
10
```

To encapsulate this functionality, you can create a new class called `RoomTracker` (or something similarly named to denote the action of tracking the previous rooms) and implement it as follows:

```
public class RoomTracker {

    private final Deque<Integer> rooms = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public void addRoomNumber(Integer roomNumber) {
        rooms.push(roomNumber);
    }

    public Integer getPreviousRoomNumber() {
        return rooms.pop();
    }
}
```

In a similar fashion as before, you can use this code as follows:

```
RoomTracker tracker = new RoomTracker();
tracker.addRoomNumber(10);
tracker.addRoomNumber(20);
System.out.println(tracker.getPreviousRoomNumber());
tracker.addRoomNumber(30);
System.out.println(tracker.getPreviousRoomNumber());
System.out.println(tracker.getPreviousRoomNumber());
```

This will produce the following output:

```
20
30
10
```

If you need to track the direction in which you entered the room (so that you find if a player is going to a previous room), you can create a class called `Room` and store the randomly generated number and the direction in which the player entered:

```
public enum Direction {
    TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT;
}

public class Room {

    private final int number;
    private final Direction enteredFrom;

    public Room(int number, Direction enteredFrom) {
        this.number = number;
        this.enteredFrom = enteredFrom;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public Direction getEnteredFrom() {
        return enteredFrom;
    }
}
```

You can then redefine `RoomTracker` in terms of `Room`:

```
public class RoomTracker {

    private final Deque<Room> rooms = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public void addRoom(Room room) {
        rooms.push(room);
    }

    public Room getPreviousRoom() {
        return rooms.pop();
    }
}
```

You can then push `Room` objects onto the stack as the player travels from one room to the next. For example:

```
RoomTracker tracker = new RoomTracker();
tracker.push(new Room(10, Direction.LEFT);   // Travel right into room 10
tracker.push(new Room(20, Direction.TOP);    // Travel down into room 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help a bit. I would suggest you have a game state, this handles drawing, moving, key events like your current `Executable` class.

Basic overview of what is below. The `GameState` has a reference to a `currentRoomState` this is what you should deem the character is in. Upon moving to a door, you will need to check for this, the call to `currentRoomState.MoveToNextRoom()` with the appropreate parameters.

This will trigger the current room state to generate a new room, set the reference to the new room to be tied to the correct door, place the character at the correct door in the new room, tie a refernce to the old room in the new room and set the current room to the new room.

When you move to a door that has a previous room tied to it, the variables will have been persisted.

Best of luck

-Chris

eg:

```
class GameState{
            RoomState startingRoomState = new RoomState();
            RoomState currentRoomState = startingRoomState;

            public void move(int x, int y)
            {
                currentRoomState.iCharacterPosX += x;
                currentRoomState.iCharacterPosY += y;

                // Check if need to move to a new room (eg move north)
                currentRoomState = currentRoomState.MoveToNextRoom(true, false, false, false);
            }

            public void draw()
            {
                //Based on the character pos and draw variables in currentRoomState
            }
}
```

And then you have a room state, which describes a room

```
class RoomState{
                //Where the doors are
                boolean northDoor = false;
                boolean eastDoor = false;
                boolean southDoor = false;
                boolean westDoor = false;

                // Reference to the room adjacent rooms
                RoomState rs_NorthDoor = null;
                RoomState rs_EastDoor = null;
                RoomState rs_SouthDoor = null;
                RoomState rs_WestDoor = null;

                int iCharacterPosX = 0;
                int iCharacterPosY = 0;

                // Initial
                RoomState(){
                    northDoor = true; eastDoor = true; southDoor = true; westDoor = true;
                }

                RoomState(RoomState prevState, boolean north, boolean east, boolean south, boolean west){
                    // Randomise door states

                    // Put character in the position he should be
                    iCharacterPosX = 0;//right most x Coord - oldX
                    iCharacterPosX = 0;//bottom most y Coord - oldy

                    if(north)
                    {
                        rs_NorthDoor = prevState;
                    } //elseif other doors
                }

                public RoomState MoveToNextRoom(boolean north, boolean east, boolean south, boolean west){
                    if(north){
                        if(rs_NorthDoor == null)
                        {
                            rs_NorthDoor = new RoomState(this, north, east, south, west);
                        }
                        return rs_NorthDoor;
                    } //else if the others

                    return null;
                }
            }
```